# Doubts about Bodyweight Workout to lose fat and gain strength

Tags: weight-loss, workout-routines, bodyweight-exercises

As the title says I have some *doubts* about my routine:

- Is it enough to reach my goal?

**Short term** goal: relatively *flat belly* and reach *5* complete *pull-ups*.

**Long term** goal: roughly *10% body fat* and *balance* strength and endurance.

I prefer strenght and endurance over hypertrophy.

My **nutrition is balanced** and correct.

Brief description about *my fitness journey*:

**Start** at age 20 with **97 kg** weight, **214 lb**, 168 cm tall, 5 ft 6 in.

I've *never* had any kind of fitness activity *until* few years ago.

I was *very fat* until *2 years ago* when I've joined a gym and started a mixture of bodyweight exercises, weight lifting and cardio.

My workout routine was scheduled by the gym trainer.

I've **gained** some **strength**, some muscle **volume** and **lost a lot of fat**.
My health improved consistently and I'm happier than before.

After ~**14 months**, I've switched doing my **own schedule** and after my membership ended I've **switched** to **train** at the **park** that has a wonderful structure to do bodyweight exercises.

Due to the fact that I'm a University **student** I had to schedule my train during the entire week, with access to the park **only** in the weekend.

My **routine** is:

- *Monday* | Rest or Jumping Rope
- *Tuesday* | Aikido
- *Wednesday* | Jumping Rope
- *Thursday* | Aikido
- *Friday* | Jumping Rope
- *Saturday* | Upper Body
- *Sunday* | Rest or Lower Body

Legend:

**Jumping Rope** | **5 sets** of jumps | **60s rest** between sets

**Upper Body** | 3x5 Negative **Chin-Ups** | 3x8 **Inverted Row** | 3x16 **Push-Ups** | 3x10 **Pike Push-Ups**

**Lower Body** | 3x5 Assisted One Leg **Squat** | 3x20 **Calf Raises** | 3x10 Parallel Bar **Dips**

**Aikido** is a martial art that I do every Tuesday and Thursday evening from 20:30 to 22:00, 1h 30m a day, 3h a week total.

**Now**: Age 22 years old and 72 kg, 159 lb

Notes:

Jumping Rope | I usually jump as long as possible during a set, 5 sets can last from 30 to 45 minutes.

The reason of the Rest|Jumping Rope on Monday is due to the fact that sometimes I give my body some break, it depends on what I've done on Sunday.

Upper Body | Negative chin ups due to the fact that I can't do 1 regular chin up yet.

Comment: Note, your goals represent that of someone striving for strength with someone striving for aesthetic. You will always struggle to progress towards your strength goals while eating at a caloric deficit. There is a reason entrants into strongman competitions are not "ripped".

Comment: My nutrition is balanced, my only concern is about my routine.
Is it enough to train 1-2 days a week to gain strength?

Or is it a matter of nutrition?
I don't want to became a strongman, just stronger than now.

Comment: Nutrition and calorie intake are separate. To become strong you should be training at least 3 times a week on compound barbell exercises.

Comment: I can't use barbells. The only place where I can train is this park that I've mentioned that has a structure to do some calisthenics.

Answer (score 3):

To lower body fat, provided nutrition is correct: **Calories In** must be less than **Calories Out**.

> What should I eat for weight loss?   Eat less. Different diets can
> make this easier, so pick whichever one best fits your lifestyle.
> Ultimately, you need to reduce your caloric intake.
>
> Source: [examine.com](https://examine.com/nutrition/what-should-i-eat-for-weight-loss/)

Exercise will help you reach this goal but your focus for weight loss should be diet. Opinion on what a balance of strength and endurance looks like is very subjective so you wont get an answer for that.